# Android : Need guidance with Complex Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a page where I got the user to select different types of colors. Types include

1. Color1
2. Color2
3. Font Color
4. Background Color

   This much is fine, but more complex is for each colorType I got to provide selection with RGB - having a Slider/Seek for R, g,  & B respectively for each color Type.

*NOTE* : ColorPicker's not allowed only selection in RGB.

I got to add above 4 selections + a button to show the result.

According to you what should be the best layout to implement the above screen. I started with a LinearLayout where the root's orientation is horizontal & it has 2 inner LinearLayouts whose orientation is vertical. The 1st child can have Color1 & Color2 & 2nd child Font & Background. And Show a button on bottom.

Any better option to implement this more easily. Can TableLayout be a better option ? Or any other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a really complex layout IMHO. What you are doing is just fine.

You could make it more cleaner if you make a Spinner to choose what type of color you are changing, and then hiding and showing vertical LinearLayout 's.

The seekbars I'd say thay have to be in vertical because of the size.

Comment: Oh, so I can add 4 color types in Spinner and show respective values of RGB of selected Item - that's much better & cleaner approach. Thanks sfratini.